# Google Map Image retrieval

Tags: google-maps

Can anyone say how to retrieve a satellite image of an area specified, in the form of an image ?

I prefer java code.

I have tried the following code in javascript. But it's not responding.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps API - Map Type</title>
<style type="text/css">
div #map {
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadGoogleMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(8.70386, 77.11423);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 13,
        center : latlng,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        mapTypeControlOptions : {
            style : google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
            position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
        position : latlng,
        map : map,
        title : ""
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadGoogleMap()">
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want an image (and to comply with the terms of use), you should investigate the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en).  You don't say why you need an image, make sure you are complying with the terms.

Comment: I want to get the soil image for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following java code:-

```
String temp;
Image image = null;
temp="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitude+","+longitude+"& zoom=18&size=100x100&sensor=false&maptype=satellite";
URL url = new URL(temp);
image = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "jpg",new File("D:\\map.jpg"));

// give the latitude and the longitude as 25.165173,47.237548
```

And run the code you will the image of  an area in Saudi Arabia.